# Support for read-only properties in Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

Our repository entities have audit/log properties like (`createdDate`, `updatedDate`...) that are assigned by the application and should be read-only properties to the user. A little bit of research on [Jackson showed this feature is not supported](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/95) (or is it?). Wondering if SDR could be of any help here?

```java
@Document(collection="employees")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private firstName;
    private lastName;
    
    //read-only attribute. initially assigned by application and should not be changed
    private Date createdDate;
    
    //read-only attribute. initially assigned by application and should not be changed
    private Employee createdBy;
    
    //getters setters truncated....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

org.springframework.data.annotation.ReadOnlyProperty is added in spring-data-commons 1.9.0.

This serves the purpose. Please refer:

- https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-534
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/pull/88

Comment: I don't think this achieves the stated goals, as this completely prevents the property from being written.  However, what is being asked for is preventing the property from being written when sent from the REST API, but allowing the application to still set these properties programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

The Jackson issue you linked to ([jackson-databind#95](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/95)) has since been implemented.  That feature allows using [`@JsonIgnoreProperties(allowGetters=true)`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html#allowGetters--) to include the data when writing the JSON, but exclude it when reading it.

This feature alone isn't sufficient to get Spring Data REST to ignore properties, since it'll result in these properties always being `null` when updated.

Comment: Works for me as I update the created by and modified by with one of the event listeners. Thanks, 1 upvote from me!

Answer (score 0):

Using spring-data-rest with spring-data-jpa, i have had success using jpa @Column(updatable = false).

Looks like you're not using JPA (@Document), does your persistence framework have an annotation to indicate a read-only field?

Furthermore, having a getter but not a setter could be part of the puzzle. In my case spring-data-jpa AuditingEntityListener sets the field, so i do not need a  setter in the application code.

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AuditedEntity extends AuditedUpdateEntity {

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private DateTime createdTs;

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private String createdBy;

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public DateTime getCreatedTs() {
        return createdTs;
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. I need to use Spring Mongo @Document 2. I need setters since the application code assigns values to these properties. They are readonly only to the client.